# Multiple database insertion though AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to insert multiple records through JS function.JS function calls action of another YII controller that performs insertion.

I am reading the data from a MySql table performing some actions on data and saving the changed data to an array post_data. Later I am converting this array to url format and passing as parameter to JS function. This function has ajax to call another controller to perform insertion.

I am trying to insert to 2 tables. 1st contact_details table is inserted and then engineer table is inserted, so I want this ajax call to run in serial way. i.e, I want next insertion to start only after the previous insertion is complete.

My code is:

```
<script>

     function call_migration_api(post_data)
    {
      //console.log( 'post data in js func = '+post_data); 

      //var db_data = post_data.serialize();//tried this, but not working.
     var db_data = post_data;

     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:"http://localhost/amica_migration/rapport/chs/Migrationapi/createengineer",
          data: db_data,
          success: function(server_response)
          {
             console.log(server_response)
          }//end of success

     });//end of $.ajax


   }//end of function.

</script>

<?php

   //reading all values in $post_data array.

   foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) 
    {
        $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
    }
    $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

    echo "<script>call_migration_api('$post_string');</script>";// Call to AJAX function.



?>
```

Migration API code:

```
<?php

      public function actionCreateEngineer()
      {
            $engineer_model=new Engineer();
    $contactdetails_model=new ContactDetails();

            //****** RETRIVING CONTACT DETAILS ***********
            $contactdetails_model->address_line_1= $_POST['address_line_1'];
    $contactdetails_model->town= $_POST['town'];
    $contactdetails_model->postcode_s= $_POST['postcode_s'];
    $contactdetails_model->postcode_e= $_POST['postcode_e'];
    $contactdetails_model->telephone= $_POST['telephone'];
    $contactdetails_model->email= $_POST['email'];

        //********** SAVING CONTACT ***************
    if($contactdetails_model->save())
    {
        echo "<br>Contact Model Saved";

        $engineer_model->contact_details_id=$contactdetails_model->id;
        $engineer_model->delivery_contact_details_id=$contactdetails_model->id;

                    //****** RETRIVING ENGINEER DETAILS ***********
        $engineer_model->first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
        $engineer_model->last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
        $engineer_model->active=$_POST['active'];
        $engineer_model->id=$_POST['engg_id'];


            //****** SAVING ENGINEER DETAILS ***********    
        if($engineer_model->save())
        {
            echo "<br>Engineer saved";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<br>Engineer not saved******** ENGG ERROR = ";
            print_r($engineer_model->getErrors());
        }


    }//end of if contact save.
    else
    {
        echo "<br>Contacts NOT SAVED ///////// CONTACT ERROR = ";
        print_r($contactdetails_model->getErrors());
    }

      }//end of create engineer.

?>
```

Comment: read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: What is `post_data` supposed to be? Can you explain in detail how your code does/should work? What starts off the entire process (page load, form submit, etc)? What does the first AJAX call send? What happens on the server? What does the server response contain? How is the second AJAX request triggered?

Comment: Could you add how url:"http://localhost/amica_migration/rapport/chs/Migrationapi/createengineer" processes your data